# DIV background image swap on link rollover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to swap out the background image on a div when the user rolls over a link.

What am I doing wrong? This isn't working.

```
<style>
#divToSwap {
    background-image: url(black.jpg);
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="divToSwap"></div>
<div>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"
        onmouseover="document.getElementById('divToSwap').backgroundImage='url(red.jpg)';"
        onmouseout="document.getElementById('divToSwap').backgroundImage='url(black.jpg)';">
        Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"
        onmouseover="document.getElementById('divToSwap').backgroundImage='url(blue.jpg)';"
        onmouseout="document.getElementById('divToSwap').backgroundImage='url(black.jpg)';">
        Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"
        onmouseover="document.getElementById('divToSwap').backgroundImage='url(green.jpg)';"
        onmouseout="document.getElementById('divToSwap').backgroundImage='url(black.jpg)';">
        Green</a></li>        
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, e.g.

`document.getElementById('divToSwap').style.backgroundImage='url(black.jpg)';`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementById('divToSwap').style.backgroundImage=...
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('divToSwap').backgroundImage=....
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.style` is missing:

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('divToSwap').style.backgroundImage='url(red.jpg)';"
```